# Modules in Javascript with eval();

Tags: javascript, security, module, eval

Every javascript developer knows; eval is evil

But since i am looking for the ultimative module technology in javascript, i read something very interesting about someone using eval as a module loader, which has 2 main benefits:

- Faster loading for mobile, because its loading a whole string at once
- Script seperating without doing fancy define wrappers like require.js in each module

So whats all about that? And could it be a solution, to only load several functions through eval? I mean from security aspects...

Edit: sry forgot the link to the article: [Article](http://tomdale.net/2012/01/amd-is-not-the-answer/)

Comment: I think evaling static strings that you have 100% control over (your code - that you were planning on executing anyway, just lazy loaded) is fine.

Comment: I don't really understand why you would load code as a string, not as a script file, and why that would be faster?

Comment: Hard to debug evaluated script. No optimization. But this is "good eval": http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kdwwvps4J9A

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because of the high-latency on 3G connections a single HTTP request, even with more data, is often a lot faster then multiple smaller requests.

What that article proposes is combining multiple modules into one file like this:

```
var modules = {
    'main.js': 'alert("Main module")',
    'another.js': 'alert("Another module")',
    'notUsed.js': 'alert("I am never used")',
};
```

That way they can all be downloaded with a single HTTP request which is faster, and you can still only include/evaluate the modules you need.

e.g. you could do:

```
var requireFile = function(file) {
    if(modules[file])
        eval(modules[file]);
};

requireFile('main.js');
requireFile('another.js');
```

and only `main.js` and `another.js` would be evaluated, `notUsed.js` would just be ignored.

Security wise, it shouldn't be any different to including them via the `<script>` tag provided whatever you use to combine the scripts can't accidentally combine/include other files/strings too.

So from a security perspective, there shouldn't any difference from the above and this:

```
<script src="main.js"></script>
<script src="another.js"></script>
```

Of course you still have the [other disadvantages of eval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea).

Comment: I'm running issues with requirejs/ember and am considering going this route. It looks simple on the surface to implement, but I have not seen any libraries to do this. Are there any sizeable projects doing doing this right now? I'm afraid of running into issues later (e.g, performance).

Comment: What is a <scruipt> tag?